# How to move text to the center with Wrap

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a struggle to move the text to center with Wrap. I want the beach and colon to be aligned with the circle. I have modified my code but it doesn't seem to move. Is anyone knows how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `crossAlignment`. and I also suggest to use spacing instead of manual padding

```
 child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        spacing: 8, // horizontal
        runSpacing : 10 // vertical
      ....
```

[image]